# Rename table or column in SQL server without breaking existing apps

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an existing database in MS SQL server and want to rename some tables and columns because the names currently used aren't accurate to what it represents.

I have multiple web and desktop applications that access the database, using Entity Framework (code first). Too many to update in one go and cannot afford for all apps to start working.

I was thinking it was nice is SQL server allowed a 'permanent' alias for tables and columns but I don't think this feature exists.

Or I was wondering if there was a way in EF to have two names for the same property?

Comment: You could rename the tables to whatever - but then create a View which accesses the data from those tables with the aliased name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the tables, you could rename them and then create a synonym with the old name pointing to the new name.

For the columns, changing their name will break your application.You could create computed columns with the old name as well, that simply display the value of the new named column though (but this seems a little silly).

Note, however, that a computed column cannot reference another computed column, so you would have to duplicate the column in its entirety. That could lead to problems down the line if you don't update the definition of both columns.

Comment: Thanks for this, that's answered my main requirement, I can't believe I've never come across synonyms before!

Comment: As for columns, I think I'll create a new column with the same data from the old column and use triggers to keep the column data in sync until I can update all the apps to use the new column names

Comment: Triggers would seem like a bad idea @User . That's unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Adding new columns and populating with triggers is not the best option. You don’t need to be duplicating the data. This is too prone to a mistake. This also seems like more of a hassle to keep both columns in sync.

Comment: You don't even need a trigger, just a calculated column. But it's still a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

A view containing a simple select statement acts exactly like a table. You really need to fix this properly across the database and applications. However if you want to go the view route, I suggest you do this:

Say you have a table called `MyTable` that you rename `TheTable` and with a column called `MyColumn` that you want to rename to `TheColumn`

1. Create a schema, say, `new`
2. Move the original table into it with this `ALTER SCHEMA new TRANSFER MyTable`
3. Rename the table and column.

Now you have a table called `new.TheTable` with a column called `TheColumn`. Everything is broken

Lastly, create a view that looks just like the old table

```
 CREATE VIEW dbo.MyTable 
 AS 
 SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, TheColumn As MyColumn 
 FROM new.TheTable;
```

Now everything works again.

- All your fixed 'new' tables are in the `new` schema
- However now everything is extra complicated

This is basically an illustration that you should just fix it properly across the whole app one at a time with careful change management. Definitely don't complicate it with triggers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using code first with multiple web and desktop applications, you are likely managing database changes from one place through migrations and ignoring changes other places.
You can create an empty migration and add code that will change the table name and column names to what you want. The migration should then create a view that will select from that table with the original table and column names. When you apply this migration, everything should still be working as normal from all applications. There are no model changes since you didn’t touch the model classes. Inserts, updates, and deletes will still happen through the view.  There is no need for potentially buggy triggers or synonyms on the table in this option.
Now that you have the table changed, you can focus on the application code.  If it helps, you can add annotations over the column and table names and start refactoring the code. You need to make sure you don’t make model changes that will break the other apps. If apps ignore model changes, you can get away with adding annotations over the columns and classes on all the apps before refactoring. You can get rid of the view sooner this way.